# How to sum props sent by a root component

Tags: reactjs

Having a root component (App) I want to pass the data from the root component to the Total component. The goal is to return the total of the data passed through props (10+7+14=31).

I did it like you can see on the code below, and it works. But I don't understand why should I call this variable exercises3:

```
<Total  exercises3={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}/>
```

If I change the variable name to for example, totalExcersises, it does not work. Why?

```
<Total  totalExcersises={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}/>
```

I feel there should be a better way to get the total of the data passed through props anyway.

Here is my code:
[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-leaf-29bp4?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from 'react'


const Total= (props) => {
  return(
 <p>Number of exercises: {props.exercises1} {props.exercises2} {props.exercises3}</p> 

      )
}




const App = () => {
  
  const exercises1 = 10

  const exercises2 = 7

  const exercises3 = 14

  return (
    <div>
 
      <Total  exercises3={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}/>
      
  
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: made your use case dynamic instead static with sample json data, this might help you if you need it, checkout - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-get-total--count-40fxe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this,

```
import React from 'react'


const Total= ({ totalExercises }) => (
 <p>Number of exercises: {totalExercises}</p> 
 );




const App = () => {
  const exercises1 = 10

  const exercises2 = 7

  const exercises3 = 14

  return (
    <div>
      <Total totalExercises={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The "Total" Component is now looking for a prop that is called "totalExercises", so if u rename the prop-var the component can't find it any more. You always need to rename both.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `{props.totalExcersises}` in your Total component.

```
<p>Number of exercises: {props.totalExcersises} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong anyway. You give it only the prop `exercises3` but you display `{props.exercises1} {props.exercises2} {props.exercises3}` in your Total component.
just pass `totalExcersises={exercises1+exercises2+exercises3}` And adjust your code like so:
`<p>Number of exercises: {props.totalExcersises} </p>`

Answer (score -1):

"If I change the variable name to for example, totalExcersises, it does not work. Why?"

That variable name is important, React uses it when assigning values to props. If it's called `totalExcersises` you need to do `props.totalExcersises` in the Total component.

This is NOT accurate. But to help illustrate why it's important, React is kind of doing something like this:

```js
const Total = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
}

const App = () => {

  const exercise1 = 10

  const exercise2 = 7

  const exercise3 = 14

  return (
    Total({
      totalExercises: exercise1 + exercise2 + exercise3
    })
  )

}

App()
```